# 2015 Fiat 500e maintenance schedule - 15K mile interval OK?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance, electric-vehicle, fiat

I just bought a 2015 Fiat 500e (the electric version) with 25K miles. Before I bought it, the dealership had it fully serviced and inspected. I also had a pre-purchase inspection that showed no problems. The next scheduled maintenance is at 30K miles and then 40K miles. Can I just wait for 40K to take it in, or should I really take it in at 30K miles?

Comment: Is what the dealer did stamped in the service log book as "the 30K service, but done at 25K" or do you have some separate paperwork? If it's not in the logbook, getting the manufacturer's service schedule done at 30K is probably better for the car in the long run, than getting the dealer to sign the book for something they didn't do to make the log book look nice.

Comment: Good point. The car didn't come with a logbook. I plan to keep the car until it dies - should I get one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some value the service record being complete - in 5 years time “we missed that service because...” may not sound so convincing when you try and sell it...

Do the 30k service, the “full service” by the dealer may not be a full service but a “quick look & inspect & top up”....